# High school-level geometry book focusing on game dev for struggling student?

Tags: mathematics, geometry, books

Here's the situation.  My brother, a freshman in high school, isn't doing too well in geometry.  Partially because he doesn't do half the work, but partially because he seems to have genuine difficulty with the material.  So then I thought, since geometry is so useful in game dev, why not get him a book that presents geometry concepts in that light so that he can better grasp them?

Note that he doesn't actually want to make video games, so coding is not important, only an understanding of geometry that'll get him through the rest of the year.  He does like video games, however.  A book in game-focused geometry would serve as supplementary to his schoolwork, not as a substitute.  To be concise, this is exactly what I need;

- 2D only!  3D is not relevant here!
- Not much focus on programming (or it can at least be bypassed).
- Good for high school freshmen who are just trying to get a B and get out.
- Direct applications are important, but if the explanations are super clear then this can be forgiven.  For instance, http://tinyurl.com/83e9wsu I've skimmed this book and can safely say that it'll be great for his required Algebra II and Trig course next year, even though its relation to game development is pretty much in name only.

Comment: What is your skill level? Can you teach him?

Comment: Not as well as I'd like.  I'm better at teaching computer science/programming than math.  I didn't pay much attention when I was in Geometry, anyway.  I was able to skate by with an A, but I didn't absorb the material well, so I'd be relearning much of it myself.  Plus, I've tried tutoring him in the past, and for all the time I spend his grades don't improve too much.  He already does go to a tutor, by the way.

Answer (score 3):

A book on video game geometry is probably not going to help your brother much. It will talk about mathematics topics used in *video games*, not necessarily those covered in his curriculum, and may entirely skip over certain things he needs to know to pass his subjects.

Plus, just because it's related to video games doesn't mean it's going to be fun - it's a maths book either way.

#### Have you tried pointing your brother to [Khan Academy](http://www.khanacademy.org/)?

It's a free (as in Wikipedia) library of lectures which cover, among other things, almost every topic in the American curriculum [including geometry](http://www.khanacademy.org/#core-geometry). They're short and explained in a way that's quite easy to understand. If your brother is struggling because he doesn't quite understand how to do things, rest assured he'll be able to learn from Khan Academy.

Comment: The idea isn't to make it fun, it's to make it different.  But I hadn't thought of Khan, will do, thanks!

Comment: @Jesse So what you're after is explanations that would work for him?

Comment: Yes, pretty much.  But I'd like to try something different as well, and this is how I'm going about it.